# Element invisible on pressed enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

This time... I'm trying to create a function where the element is supposed to show when the user would press the Enter Key. However, the keypress function does not work.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        if (inputBox.value === "")
        {
            alert("Write plz");
        }
        else
        {
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
            list_li.appendChild(li);
        }
    }});
```

Comment: can please explain more?

Comment: i think there is a chance inputBox or list_li aren't properly initialized.

Comment: If the field is in a form, you need to preventDefault and you can just assign the event handler to the submit event without the need to test the key. Also no need for jQuery at all here

Comment: This API is [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/keypress-shorthand/#:~:text=This%20API%20is%20deprecated) in favour of [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/#on1)

Answer (score 0):

Your script works with these fields and jQuery loaded

```js
const list_li = document.getElementById("list_li");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    if (inputBox.value === "") {
      alert("Write plz");
    } else {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
      list_li.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputBox" value="" />
<ul id="list_li"></ul>
```

However I recommend to consolidate on jQuery or no jQuery. Note that it is preferable to use the `.on("keypress")` event handler rather than the deprecated `.keypress`

```js
$(function() {
  const $list_li = $("#list_li");
  const $inputBox = $("#inputBox");
  $(document).on("keypress",function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      const val = $inputBox.val().trim();
      if (val === "") {
        alert("Write plz");
        return;
      }
      let $li = $("<li/>").text(val);
      $list_li.append($li);
      $inputBox.val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputBox" value="" />
<ul id="list_li"></ul>
```

If the field is in a form, you need to preventDefault and you can just assign the event handler to the submit event without the need to test the key.

Also no need for jQuery at all here

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page has loaded
  const list_li = document.getElementById("list_li");
  const inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = inputBox.value.trim();
    if (value === "") {
      alert("Write plz");
      return;
    }
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
    list_li.appendChild(li);
    inputBox.value = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" id="inputBox" value="" />
</form>

<ul id="list_li"></ul>
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that `.keypress` has been [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/keypress-shorthand/#:~:text=This%20API%20is%20deprecated) in favour of [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/#on1)

Comment: I did not even know, I always use the .on but missed it here